# Javascript throwing undefined error on second execution of function in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am drawing shapes onto a canvas with JS and jQuery. I have a render loop function that redraws the shapes using information from an object. This object has been defined and the code runs through the loop once, then the object becomes undefined and I am lost to why. I don't do much JS, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious. I've checked a load of other threads but can't seem to find why my value is changing to an undefined state after having been defined. Below is a simplified version of the code:

```
$document.ready{

    const canvas = $canvas;
    const context = canvas.getContext();

    const 2dArray = [ [...], ..., [...] ];
    const object = { coords: {x:5, y:5}, shape: 2dArray};
    render(canvas, context, object);
});

function render(canvas, context, object){
    drawFunction(canvas, context, object);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

function drawFunction(canvas, context , object){
    drawShape(context, object.coords, object.shape);
};
```

Quick simplified runthrough:

- drawShape(): iterates through a 2D array to form a "shape" from a 3x3 grid of squares.
- drawFunction(): executes drawShape() and a few other bits.
- render(): recursive function to continously draw & redraw canvas.

What is happening is that drawFunction() is executing once in the render loop, then once it goes to execute a second time, and execute drawShape() a second time, "object" has now become undefined. I don't understand this as it has already been defined and used? The shape *is* being drawn once but then something goes wrong.

Any help appreciated, feel free to tell me I'm a moron having missed something stupid and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` calls the given function without any arguments. So `render()` function won't receive any parameters on the second time. To solve the problem, you could use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind arguments on the function.

```js
function render(canvas, context, object){
    drawFunction(canvas, context, object);
    requestAnimationFrame(render.bind(null, canvas, context, object));
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much! I'm not used to Js syntax due to mainly working with C++/C# etc, so I doubt I would have worked this out. Thanks!